# Javascript Arrays and .forEach Loop Arguments

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

In the `listTodos()` function, I can't figure out how/why the `i` placeholder argument for the `todos.forEach` loop spits out the array's index numbers. To me, it seems that both placeholder/arguments would do the same thing, as I cant figure out how they're specified any different from one another.

So below, I don't understand why the console wouldn't log: `"Buy New Turtle: Buy New Turtle"`, as opposed to: `"0: Buy New Turtle"`.

```js
todos.forEach(function(todo, i) {
console.log(i + ": " + todo);
```

Here is the whole "Todo List" JS code:

```js
var todos = ["Buy New Turtle"];

var input = prompt("What would you like to do?");

while(input !== "quit") {
  if(input === "list") {
   listTodos();
  }
  else if(input === "new") {
 addTodo();
  }
  else if(input === "delete") {
   deleteTodo();
  }
  input = prompt("What would you like to do?");
}
console.log("OK YOU QUIT THE APP");

function listTodos() {
 console.log("**********")
   todos.forEach(function(todo, i) {
 console.log(i + ": " + todo);
    });
    console.log("**********");
}

function addTodo() {
 var newTodo = prompt("Enter new todo");
 todos.push(newTodo);
 console.log("Added Todo");
}

function deleteTodo() {
 var index = prompt("Enter Index of Todo to Delete");
   todos.splice(index, 1);
   console.log("Deleted Todo");
}
```

So... Am I making any sense here? Can someone clear this up for me? Thanks!

Comment: The second argument passed to the `.forEach()` callback is the index. The first argument is a value from the array. It'll also pass the array itself as the third parameter.

Comment: *" I can't figure out how/why the i placeholder argument for the todos.forEach loop spits out the array's index numbers."* Because that's how `forEach` was designed.  What else do you want to know about it?

Comment: [Here's the MDN page on `.forEach()`.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Comment: That's why they have something called API documentations for a reason

Comment: So .forEach  arguments always operate in a pattern of .forEach(value, index, value, index, etc)

Comment: Not sure what you mean. The callback passed to `forEach` always gets passed three arguments: the current value, the current index and the array that is iterated over. Have a look at the documentation if you haven't yet.

Comment: If you do a [Google search using the title of your question](https://www.google.com/search?q=Javascript+Arrays+and+.forEach+Loop+Arguments), you will find numerous pages that explain this. Also to answer a more general question you may have, many JavaScript functions take more than one argument, such as `Math.pow(base,exponent)`. The entire purpose of having more than one argument is that you can give a different value to each one, such as `Math.pow(2,3)` which calculates 2 to the 3rd power.

Comment: @user7361178 tdid you read the MDN documentation? The parameters to the callback are `(value, index, array)`. The callback is invoked once for each element in the array.

Comment: Evidently I need to relearn .forEach loops. This is the first time I've seen a .forEach() with more than one argument, I thought.

Comment: That's because in most cases you only need the array elements themselves. It's less common to need the index, so is usually omitted. It's even less common to need the entire array. But if you do have a second or third parameter in your callback, those receive the index and the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're passing a function as the argument to `forEach`. The `forEach` then iterates your array in a loop, and invokes that function, passing in certain arguments to that function. The arguments passed will always be...

1. the current item in the loop
2. the current index of the loop
3. the original Array.

---

To more clearly understand this, implement your own functional iterator:

```js
Array.prototype.mySuperForEach = function(callback) {
  for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    callback(this[i], i, this) // <---This is your function being invoked
  }
};

["foo", "bar", "baz"].mySuperForEach(function(item, i, arr) {
  console.log("%s: %d of %d", item, i, arr.length)
})
```

This is not a fully conforming implementation of `.forEach()`, but it gives a basic idea of what's going on. Notice that inside the `for` loop, the callback is invoked and is passed the arguments you observed in your original example.

---

Note that while I extended `Array.prototype`, you shouldn't do this without *fully* understanding the ramifications thereof.